# Uses for canvas | Practical examples

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to understand what people use canvas for?

I see it on job postings I read about it in Definitive JavaScript, but I don't quite get what it is used for.

I understand that you can draw 2d or 3d ( usually 2d ) objects but why no just use Gimp or Photoshop and upload the image.

Is it so you can create dynamic images based on say...user-specific data?

What is a practical example or perhaps a link to a professional implementation of canvas ( Definite JavaScript show basis stuff like drawing circles ).

[MDN Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial)

Comment: One use-case I had to deal with - generating grayscale versions of admin-uploaded images for mouseover effects.

Comment: PHP (server side language) can do this....imaged editing..why would you need cavnas?

Comment: Because using PHP uses twice as much bandwidth and load time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used a canvas to draw a graph, and it falls back to requesting a PHP-generated image if the browser doesn't support `<canvas>`. It's always a good idea to delegate processing from the server to the client, as this places less load on the server. In other words, instead of the server going "here's the stuff", it's more like "here's the data and the instructions to show it".

Another use I've seen is to highlight areas of an imagemap when moused over.

`<canvas>` is central in HTML5 game development, since it is used to draw the entire game viewport. Without it, there is no game.

Comment: Games...and client side delegation...seems like the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it so you can create dynamic images based on say...user-specific data?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

We used <canvas> to build interactive design editor for apparel in our e-commerce store — http://printio.ru/tees/new

The kind of interactivity we provide was only possible with Flash until recently.

Even on back end, we use Node.js and <canvas>-based image processing+generation to take data from online editor and create designs that are later used in [store](http://printio.ru/store). These canvas-generated designs are eventually printed out on tshirts, mugs, caps, bags, and so on.

I think that's a pretty practical example :)

This is all done via [Fabric.js canvas library](http://fabricjs.com) (developed by us as well).

Answer (score 0):

`<canvas>` is used for better Performance. `<canvas>` is much more faster and dynamic than jpeg or anything else. Example: http://www.profistart.com/internetseiten.html here was `<canvas>` used for Background.